# Java How to check value is already AES encrypted;

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have created a tool to encrypt my table data using AES encryption.

**Encryption method**

```
public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {

        byte[] cipherBytes = null;

        log.info("Started encryption...");

        System.out.println("value before encryption :" + plainText);

        log.info("value before encryption :" + plainText);

        if (plainText != null && !plainText.isEmpty()) {
            if (cipher != null && key != null) {
                byte[] ivByte = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
                IvParameterSpec ivParamsSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivByte);
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParamsSpec);
                cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
                log.info("Completed encryption.");
                log.info("Encrypted data : " + new String(cipherBytes, "UTF8"));
                System.out.println("value after encryption" + Hex.encodeHexString(cipherBytes));
                log.info("value after encryption" + Hex.encodeHexString(cipherBytes));
                return Hex.encodeHexString(cipherBytes);
            } else {
                log.info("Encryption failed, cipher, key is null.");
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Encryption failed, cipher, key  is null.");
            }

        }


        return plainText;


    }
```

- input String: **John Doee**
- encrypted output: **4aa2173cb653f89e109b23218ecaea7f**

I want to avoid double encrypting my table data. I want to check if existing record is already encrypted. Is there any way to check this?

Comment: I don't really think there is. Imagine your input being a String that simply looks like an AES encrypted String. It's probably unlikely but a possibility. If you can't make a clear definition on what the input is supposed to look like I don't really see a way.

Comment: I think the better solution for your problem is to ask yourself why the chance of double encryption even exists. If you have a table full of encrypted values why should something ever be double encrypted. If there is a possibility for this to happen, tackle that instead, because I am quite sure that's more easily fixable.

Comment: Uh, by the looks of things you're using an IV consisting of all zeros for every encryption. Unless you create a new key for each encryption you should generate a new _random_ IV each time.

Comment: @Ben think scenario like this.@While the encryption process running.new record is inserted just before the encryption completed.finally table data are inconsistent.since encrypted and decrypted records are in the table.how can i encrypt that single decrypted record.one way is to decrypt all the records or manuaaly update that single record.thats why i want to avoid double encryption.

Comment: Aside : this "new String(cipherBytes, "UTF8")" is problematic.  An encryption result is just an array of bytes and it cannot be assumed that that array of bytes will always also represent a valid UTF8 encoding of a String.

Comment: The question is already wrong. `String` is not a container for binary data. You should not have this problem. You just have to design your application protocol such that it doesn't arise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After encryption, prepend some prefix such as `AES:`. When decrypting, check for presence of the prefix (and remove it, obviously).

Plenty of cipher implementations do similar things, where the first few bytes identify the algorithm.

As with any good encryption scheme, only the key must be secret. The algorithm can be public without compromising security.

---

The only edge case is if true plaintext begins with the prefix. If you think this is worth considering then you can reduce the risk by choosing an unlikely prefix (perhaps taking advantage of knowledge of the plaintext). For further assurance you could look at the length of the input, as the length of true ciphertext is guaranteed to be a multiple of the block size.

Comment: What if a plaintext value in the table starts with `AES:`? This scheme is not reliable.

Comment: @JamesKPolk True, but there's no better way. The prefix could be arbitrarily complex so as to reduce that likelihood to the realms of practical impossibility. For further assurance you could look at the length, as the length of true ciphertext is guaranteed to be a multiple of the block size.

Comment: That's correct, however perhaps a better way is to include a MAC value like HMAC or maybe just use a mode like AES-GCM. The MAC value will only verify if the key is correct and the data has not been corrupted or tampered with. The first check would be the length of the field of course. A prefix is common, but it's usually used as a fail-fast check: if the prefix doesn't match then we know this isn't a cipher field. There is usually a more robust check that is performed after that.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Michael that it is probably best to prefix your ciphertext with some marker. But in case you can not do this, there is also a probabilistic approach:

You can not identify raw encrypted data with a 100% certainty. But depending on your plaintext you might be able to determine if it is unencrypted. For example ASCII text can be identified by the MSB. Since ciphertext should be indistinguishable from random noise, it is unlikely for encrypted data to have the same pattern.

If 10 consecutive bytes have the MSB set to zero, the chance for it to be a ciphertext is just 2<sup>-10</sup>, i.e. less than 0.1%.

But after all you encode the ciphertext as hex string, so you would need to reverse this during analysis.

If your plaintext happens to be compressed data, chances aren't that good, though, since the entropy is almost equally high as for encrypted or even random data.